# Current of Interroll EC5000 Drive Roller

Tags: power-supply, current, circuit-design

I'm designing a conveyor belt system using Interroll EC5000 drive rollers (35W 24VDC). Calculating the current from P/V I get 1.46A. However the rated current on the datasheet is 2.4A. So my question is, should I use the calculated value or rated value when determining the total amps that my 24VDC Power supply will need for multiple drive rollers?

Comment: You may also want to look at the Starting Current in the datasheet.